# BroadcastReceiver throwing out of memory error. What could be the cause and any solution?

Tags: android, performance, android-broadcast

I have the use case where, I am trying to send like 20kb of string every second from foreground service to other foreground app using Broadcast Receiver for like 30 minutes. I've noticed that the receiver app is going blank after like 8-10 minutes. I wonder what could be the issue, is sending broadcast this frequently can cause any issue?

I registered the broadcast receiver dynamically in onResume() of fragment, like defined here.

```
responseReceiver = new ResponseReceiver();
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(responseReceiver, new IntentFilter("ACTION_DATA"));
```

Comment: Are you using Global or Local broadcasts?

Comment: @Shmuel please check the updated question.

Comment: Use LocalBroadcastManager, it should solve the performance issues. See here for more information https://android.jlelse.eu/local-broadcast-less-overhead-and-secure-in-android-cfa343bb05be

Comment: @Shmuel I am broadcasting between two separate application, Local broadcast won't work here.